# How to get the available time slots for particular minutes in a mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a booking system ,which has booking collection like this

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61cb68eed0a209fa3f76335d"
  },
  "name": "string",
  "vendorId": "string",
  "serviceDate": "2021-12-29",
  "serviceStartTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:45:00.000Z"
  },
  "serviceEndTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T21:15:00.000Z"
  },
  "staffId": "string",
  "services": [
    [
      {
        "serviceName": "string",
        "servicePrice": "string",
        "gender": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "isAccepted": false,
  "isActive": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:43:42.953Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:43:42.953Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

There can be many bookings like this ,with serviceStart time and serviceEnd time for a particular serviceDate

I want to get the available time slots lets say for 45 minutes between 8 am to 8pm for showing the availability slots in a calendar for particular staffId

Is this possible in mongdb ?.Please help

Expected output

```
{
 
  slot :"11:00 - 12:00"

}

or 

{
 
  slotStartTime :"11:00",
  slotEndTime :" 12:00",


}
```

I don't mind the  format ,just need available time slots like start time and end time

**Edit**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61cb68eed0a209fa3f76335d"
  },
  "name": "string",
  "vendorId": "string",
  "serviceDate": "2021-12-29",
  "serviceStartTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:45:00Z"
  },
  "serviceEndTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T21:15:00Z"
  },
  "staffId": "string",
  "services": [
    [
      {
        "serviceName": "string",
        "servicePrice": "string",
        "gender": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "isAccepted": false,
  "isActive": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:43:42.953Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T19:43:42.953Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61cb7a9f8be10f47d4089e7b"
  },
  "name": "string",
  "vendorId": "string",
  "serviceDate": "2021-12-29",
  "serviceStartTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-29T07:45:00Z"
  },
  "serviceEndTime": {
    "$date": "2021-12-29T09:15:00Z"
  },
  "staffId": "string",
  "services": [
    [
      {
        "serviceName": "string",
        "servicePrice": "string",
        "gender": "string",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "isAccepted": false,
  "isActive": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T20:59:11.638Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-12-28T20:59:11.638Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the work you've done, and to be crystal-clear about all specifics. You've added many details within the answer proposed earlier (in comments) - those comments should be converted into details edited into your original question, along with your own work: the query you wrote, the issues you're having, expected vs actual outputs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- match the date "2021-12-29" (put any date)
- check hour for both to be `>=8` and `<=19`
- map on the range of the 2 dates difference with step 45min
  (we need this to get all slots)
- reduce to make them pairs
- unwind to make each pair separate document
- convert the dates to strings in the format `hour:min` `"slot": "15:00 - 15:45"`

*instead of 45 you can put the minutes you want like 60,15 etc

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70511915-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$serviceDate", "2021-12-29"]}}},
 {"$set":
  {"serviceStartTime":
   {"$dateFromParts":
    {"year":{"$year":"$serviceStartTime"},
     "day":{"$dayOfYear":"$serviceStartTime"},
     "hour":
     {"$switch":
      {"branches":
       [{"case":{"$lt":[{"$hour":"$serviceStartTime"}, 8]}, "then":8},
        {"case":{"$gt":[{"$hour":"$serviceStartTime"}, 19]},
         "then":19}],
       "default":{"$hour":"$serviceStartTime"}}},
     "minute":
     {"$switch":
      {"branches":
       [{"case":{"$lt":[{"$hour":"$serviceStartTime"}, 8]}, "then":0},
        {"case":{"$gt":[{"$hour":"$serviceStartTime"}, 19]},
         "then":0}],
       "default":{"$minute":"$serviceStartTime"}}}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"serviceEndTime":
   {"$dateFromParts":
    {"year":{"$year":"$serviceEndTime"},
     "day":{"$dayOfYear":"$serviceEndTime"},
     "hour":
     {"$switch":
      {"branches":
       [{"case":{"$lt":[{"$hour":"$serviceEndTime"}, 8]}, "then":8},
        {"case":{"$gt":[{"$hour":"$serviceEndTime"}, 19]}, "then":
                                                           20}],
       "default":{"$hour":"$serviceEndTime"}}},
     "minute":
     {"$switch":
      {"branches":
       [{"case":{"$lt":[{"$hour":"$serviceEndTime"}, 8]}, "then":0},
        {"case":{"$gt":[{"$hour":"$serviceEndTime"}, 19]}, "then":0}],
       "default":{"$minute":"$serviceEndTime"}}}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"slots":
   {"$map":
    {"input":
     {"$range":
      [0,
       {"$subtract":
        [{"$add":["$serviceEndTime", {"$multiply":[60, 1000]}]},
         "$serviceStartTime"]},
       {"$multiply":[45, 60, 1000]}]},
     "in":{"$add":["$serviceStartTime", "$$this"]}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"slots":
   {"$filter":
    {"input":"$slots",
     "cond":
     {"$and":
      [{"$gte":[{"$hour":"$$this"}, 8]},
       {"$lte":[{"$hour":"$$this"}, 19]}]}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"slots":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$slots",
     "initialValue":{"data":[], "prv":null},
     "in":
     {"$cond":
      [{"$eq":["$$value.prv", null]},
       {"data":"$$value.data", "prv":"$$this"},
       {"data":
        {"$concatArrays":
         ["$$value.data", [["$$value.prv", "$$this"]]]},
        "prv":"$$this"}]}}}}},
 {"$project":{"_id":0, "staffId":1, "slots":"$slots.data"}},
 {"$unwind":"$slots"},
 {"$project":
  {"staffId":1,
   "slot":
   {"$concat":
    [{"$dateToString":
      {"date":{"$arrayElemAt":["$slots", 0]}, "format":"%H:%M"}},
     " - ",
     {"$dateToString":
      {"date":{"$arrayElemAt":["$slots", 1]}, "format":"%H:%M"}}]}}}])
```

Comment: What I am looking is to check for the available slot let's say between 8 am to 9pm for a particular date lets say  2021-12-31 .I have bookings data which has booking start time and end time .Out of them I have to find all the slots lets say for 45 minutes or 60 minutes or 15 minutes available

Comment: I have updated the question ,please check

Comment: Its giving empty array :(

Comment: i updated the answer, check the online example, it doesnt give an empty array, it finds the slot, hopefully this will work as you need it.

Comment: Its giving a 90 min slot what If I want all the slots ,lets say from morning 8 ? `[{
  "slot": "17:45 - 19:15", 
},{ "slot": "17:00 - 17:45" } ,{ "slot": "16:15 - 17:00", } ,{ "slot": "08:00 - 08:45", }]`. and this slot gap is variable ?

Comment: ok i did this but the query went bigger, its not simple query to produce this output, test the example.

Comment: I have added a document array ,in question .Sorry to bother you much

Comment: See this -https://mongoplayground.net/p/iZbB_m2XlJS ,its giving no document found

Comment: ok i updated it one more check it if you can, one problem was that service had different date from service start date, anyway retry, hopefully this time its ok

Comment: I checked it ,it has got almost what I want but ,all  its giving wrong output  https://mongoplayground.net/p/kFenOBCEVDN. for the the staff2 its showing the available hours which are wrong :(

Comment: its ok i will re-check it, it was complicated query, and needed more examples also to help understand what you need. i will see it later,it fixable i think its small change, i think you need the 8:30-9:15, to become 8:00-8:45 which is the right one

Comment: Ok thanks ,also If possible to pls can you tell me profile all the slots that are available in the booking time between 8 am to 8pm neglecting the timings that are booked already :(

Comment: update the question, add good example also, i don't know how to know which are booked, which filed to check

Comment: I am designing something like this -https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-create-availability-calandar-in-mongodb-and-node-js/351769

Comment: Difficult to be completely flexible here.

What if a user wants an oddball booking time? (“I need my appointment to start at 8:07. It’s an hour long.”)

How does each service handle overlaps?

Take your barber shop - if they have 4 barbers, but your system only allows 1 person to be booked at a given time slot, you’ve got 3 barbers sitting around doing nothing…

Comment: i updated it one more, to start the slot from the minimum free hour, 8:00-8:45,
instead of 8,19 put your hours (also 20 is (19+1) replace it with (you_hour+1))

Comment: Please refrain from having further discussion here - this is not what comments are for (nor is this somewhere to negotiate for someone to continue updating their answer based on specs). If you need to talk something through, please move this conversation to [chat].

Comment: @Takis_ - There is no need to constantly revise your answer. FYI the OP provided no initial queries, no specific issues, etc. - this should have been part of the original question.

Comment: @trinity - Please note that, throughout this entire answer's comments, you keep finding flaws with the proposed answer, based on hidden requirements you keep adding, and waiting for a revised answer. Further, you have yet to show specific effort of your own. I believe that, at this point, it might be time for you to take what's been given, and attempt to work through this on your own. If you need constant iteration on any additional software work, then it might be time to pull in some consulting services (but this isn't what Stack Overflow is for)